# 12.10 suddenly bricked luks ssd

Tags: bootloader, ssd, luks

There is luks-encrypted instance, no raid, no lvm. I often look through logs and that allows me to state that everything worked fine until reboot. However, laptop had ~3 days uptime. The drive is SSD with about 40% space free, worked without issues for 7 months, `fstrim`med manually every ~2 days. Swap was never mounted, commented out a while ago in crypttab, initramfs rebuilt, not the case.

After reboot:
`cryptsetup: evms_activate is not available`
`Begin: Waiting for encrypted source device... ...`

I had no clue what could cause the situation so i decided to go live in attempt to mount it eventually and extract the data or fix things using chroot environment, but i ended up with this (screenshot taken from-under live session):

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/131458632/Screenshot%20from%202013-02-17%2004%3A29%3A55.png

So i can't mount it. Initramfs environment shows the same. Initramfs wasn't rebuilt, no kernel updates were made, nothing related to mounting was touched.

1. If it is dead, why gparted is able to recognize the table?
2. Where is drive's uuid (live usb/initramfs it used to work with)?
3. My options? (tried on different boxes, newer kernels)
4. Any guesses what went wrong in general?

Answer (score 1):

Knowing first sector of partition and it's length (in my case `parted` or `gparted` tool was the only option known to me to find out) `addpart` tool can help to add the partition. So eventually i was able to backup my data.